# Is there a way to combine all powershell commands to remove win10 bloatware rather than doing it one by one?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a way to use Windows Powershell to remove Windows 10 bloatware (Get Skype, Money, Get Groove Music, etc. etc.)
**all at once** rather than typing each remove code separately. Is there a command for this or should I just suck it up and copy each command into powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-to-use command like this. But you can write a function or a module, containing them and then just call the function.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462268/removing-windows-10-apps-with-powershell-script/35463725#35463725), this is close to what you want.

Comment: Wow, thank you. This is exactly what I needed! Now I just need to practice my acting when she ask where all the apps disappeared to.